# How can I achieve correct syntax highlighting in TeXstudio with a custom style file?

Tags: packages, texstudio, syntax-highlighting

I work in TexStudio and experience highlighting problems when using my custom .sty file. Trying to solve this issue I experimented by downloading a custom .sty file from the internet (called test.sty) and save it where MikTex stores installed Latex packages.

Here is a snapshot of my toy example:

[image]

The test.sty has a line `\newcommand{\lpto}[1]{\xrightarrow{L^{#1}}} % L^p convergence` and you see that TexStudio recognizes `$\lpto{P}$`. However, when I type the exact same command in the test.sty file:
`\newcommand{\lqto}[1]{\xrightarrow{L^{#1}}} % L^p convergence`
(so only changing the name of the command) then suddenly TexStudio no longer recognizes the command. Even after saving and closing everything and refreshing MikTex the same happens to the `\e` command (which when changed to `\fk` is no longer recognized)

Hence my question: does anyone know how to solve this highlighting issue? And how it is possible that when adding the exact same line suddenly TexStudio no longer recognizes the command?

The file still compiles though, it is just the highlighting which is very annoying, especially when you write big documents.

Comment: TeXstudio auto generates completion file (.cwl) for included packages, but that auto-generation is one-off, so the corresponding .cwl file won't dynamically update. You can provide a user .cwl file, see [introductions here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1173#issuecomment-657205098).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thanks for your answer! But how is it possible that initially newcommands like `\e` or `lpto{P}` are recognized? I.e. those commands that were already in the test.sty file when I downloaded it.

Comment: My guess is, when loaded at the first time, texstudio generates corresponding `.cwl` file for `.sty`. But the `.cwl` is not dynamically updated when `.sty` is changed.